# Why does agentless discovery uses only TCP connections?

Tags: azure, vmware, hyper-v, azure-migrate

In the [azure migrate agentless discovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/migrate/concepts-dependency-visualization), the documentation says:
After discovery of dependency data begins, polling begins:

> The Azure Migrate appliance polls TCP connection data from servers
> every five minutes to gather data.
>
> Data is collected from guest servers via vCenter Server, using vSphere
> APIs.
>
> Polling gathers this data:
>
> Name of processes that have active connections. Name of application
> that run processes that have active connections. Destination port on
> the active connections. The gathered data is processed on the Azure
> Migrate appliance, to deduce identity information, and is sent to
> Azure Migrate every six hour

Q- Why only TCP connections are considered while doing the dependency mapping? Why not UDP connections?